# Storing an average in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, average

I'm looking for a way to create an array in which it finds the average for columns E, F, G and H and then stores the average in an array. The only issue is the amount of rows in each column varies for each file I will run this array on (all the columns have the same amount of rows though) and so I pressure it'll be a dynamic array, and I also want the averaging to start from the second row as I have titles in the first row.  If anyone knows how to do this the help would be much appreciated as I'm utterly confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, empty cells doesn't count. So there is no need to define lastrow. Try this:

```
Sub AvToArray()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim col As Range
    Dim arrAv()
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("E:H")
    ReDim arrAv(rng.Columns.Count)

    For Each col In rng.Columns
        arrAv(i) = WorksheetFunction.Average(col)
        i = i + 1
    Next col

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WorksheetFunction` method for `Average()`.

From what I understood from your question, you wanted the averages to be stored inside an array, so here you go..

```
Public Function lastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1)
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, aveArr(4) As Double
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    'You said that you wanted to store the values to be inside an array...
    With WorksheetFunction
        aveArr(0) = .Average(ws.Range("E2:E" & lastRow(ws, "E")))
        aveArr(1) = .Average(ws.Range("F2:E" & lastRow(ws, "F")))
        aveArr(2) = .Average(ws.Range("G2:E" & lastRow(ws, "G")))
        aveArr(3) = .Average(ws.Range("H2:E" & lastRow(ws, "H")))
    End With

    MsgBox aveArr(0) & vbNewLine & _
            aveArr(1) & vbNewLine & _
            aveArr(2) & vbNewLine & _
            aveArr(3)

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting competition on this question.  Can I say that if there is bad data in a column and you get a #Num! then defining result array as a Double will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

My (very similar) solution to the others posted here:

```
Sub AverageArray()

Dim myarray As Variant, sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'or F, G, H, etc.

myarray = Array(Application.Average(Range("E2:E" & lastrow)), _
                Application.Average(Range("F2:F" & lastrow)), _
                Application.Average(Range("G2:G" & lastrow)), _
                Application.Average(Range("H2:H" & lastrow)))

Debug.Print myarray(0)
Debug.Print myarray(1)
Debug.Print myarray(2)
Debug.Print myarray(3)
End Sub
```